# Asynchronous database queries in PostgreSQL using drivers

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, asyncpg

I would like to use asynchronous queries in PostgreSQL. I know that some asynchronous drivers exist in many programming languages ie. asyncg (Python), vertx-postgress (Java) and so on.

Do I need to configure PostgreSQL somehow to use asynchronous features? There is an "Asynchronous Behavior" section in `postgesql.conf`. Do I need to uncomment and edit these values to use PostgreSQL 
optimally in an asynchronous way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameters in the “asynchonous behavior” section of the documentation are largely unrelated.

You should instead study the [Asynchronous Command Processing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-async.html) section. This is about the C library, but that's probably what's used by the libraries you mention under the hood.

Don't forget that there can only be one query at a time on a PostgreSQL database connection, regardless if processing is synchronous or not.

Comment: Unrelated? What about "#max_parallel_workers = 8  # maximum number of max_worker_processes that
     # can be used in parallel queries
"?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you mean by "asynchronous processing". I thought you meant starting a query, then doing something else instead of waiting until the query is done.

Comment: I just meant this exactly, but doc tells about "parallel queries", so there is a possibility to execute more than one query in the same time. Those drivers I have mentioned above, use a connection pool under the hood but if only one query will be executed in time I expect a perfomance hit anyway.

Comment: No, parallel query is several processes working on the same query. Connection pools are another concept, also unrelated to asynchronous processing.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation, Laurenz. I thought PostgreSQL can delegate separate queries to threads/workers but it turned out that is not possible nad 'Asynchronous Behavior' is completely unrelated to asynchronous queries.